# How I can improve execution time of recursive promise on Edge? On chrome it is almost instantenous for 100000 records

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recursion, microsoft-edge

In code snippet below the promise is recursively called after completion of itself. I ran the following code snippet on Edge and on Chrome and am seeing a marked difference in execution time. Is there something wrong that I am doing? How I can improve the execution time on Edge?

Please ignore the promise 'anti-pattern'. It is just to simulate an asynchronous method.

**Chrome result -**
Count - 99999
Start 1512416096194
last update 1512416096509
End 1512416096577
recursiveFnReturnsPromise finished

*execution time - 397ms*

**Edge result -**
Count - 99999 
Start 1512415183349
last update 1512415508413
End 1512415907219
recursiveFnReturnsPromise finished

*execution time between the start and the end- 723870ms*

*execution time between last the DOM update and the end- 398806ms*

```js
//large array
let aValues = Array(100000);

//utility function
function writeln(text) {
  let p = document.createElement('div');
  p.innerText = text;
  document.getElementById('v1').appendChild(p);
}


writeln('Start ' +Date.now()); //note start recursion time

recursiveFnReturnsPromiseV1(aValues, 1).then(function() {
  writeln('End ' +Date.now());//note end recursion time
  writeln('recursiveFnReturnsPromise finished');
}, function() {
  writeln('End' +Date.now());
  writeln('recursiveFnReturnsPromise failed');
})

//the recursive functions which returns a promise
function recursiveFnReturnsPromiseV1(pValues, ix) {
  if (pValues.length <= ix)
    return Promise.resolve();

  return new Promise(function(c, e) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = ix;
    if(ix==99999) writeln('last update ' +Date.now());
    c();
  }).then(function() {
    return recursiveFnReturnsPromiseV1(pValues, ++ix);
  })
}
```

```html
Count - <span id='output'></span>
<div id='v1'></div>
```

Note - for anyone interested in trying to do promise recursion right please see related post - [What is the difference in following pattern to call recursive JavaScript function which returns a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584584/what-is-the-difference-in-following-pattern-to-call-recursive-javascript-functio)

Comment: Does it make a difference if you take out that line that sets the "output" element to the index? My guess would be that Edge may be doing layout work that Chrome doesn't.

Comment: Interesting, Firefox shows a majority of time spent in "JIT" (which, uh, doesn't make sense to me). What do you see in Edge? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide/performance

Comment: Running this snippit myself, Firefox Nightly (59.0a1) => `3 611`; Edge (41.16299.15.0) => `1 607`; Chrome Canary (64.0.3282.5) => `179`. Yes, dramatically longer, but I don't see 17 seconds anywhere.

Comment: 12 *minutes*? Really?

Comment: Actually there is no promise constructor antipattern in this code, it's not creating another promise inside the `new Promise` callback. Admittedly, the synchronous fulfillment could have been simplified to `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: "*Is there something wrong that I am doing?*" - Yes: you try to "*simulate an asynchronous method*" without doing anything actually asynchronous. It's true that your results in Edge are horrific, but this is a really unusual case. Normally most of the execution time will be spent at the asynchronous task(s), not at the promises - and for looping only, a synchronous loop should be used.

Comment: If there was a real asynchronous task running within won't it only add to total execution time which we see here for Edge? Am I not understanding this correct?

Comment: A better way to simulate an asynchronous task is `await new Promise(setTimeout)`. This will allow Chrome and Firefox to draw the counter, for instance, and will match the behavior seen when performing async I/O or message passing.

Comment: FYI in case anyone wasn't aware, the promises implementation was horribly slow/broken in Edge back in 2017, this was fixed in Edge 14. The above issues can be attributed to that.

Answer (score 2):

Even without interacting with the DOM, Promises are dramatically slower in Firefox.

```
(async()=>{
  let start = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) await Promise.resolve();
  let end = Date.now();
  console.log(end-start, 'ms');
})();
```

On my machine, this completes in 0.25 seconds in Node.js, 6 seconds in Chrome, and 16 seconds in Firefox. (I don't have Edge).

I would avoid iterating over an excessive number of Promises. It should be doable — in any realistic code the majority of wall clock time will be spent rendering updates in the browser or waiting for asynchronous calls to complete, and only a small fraction will be in actually executing the asynchronous calls themselves. Perform more work synchronously if that's the case.

This is slightly faster for some reason:

```
(async()=>{
  let start = Date.now();
  await Promise.all(Array(1e6).fill(Promise.resolve()));
  let end = Date.now();
  console.log(end-start, 'ms');
})();
```

1 second in Node.js, 2.5 seconds in Chrome, 4 seconds in Firefox. (And in fact, the bulk of the work is in actually building the array, I get <1 second if I move that outside the timed section.)

Using Promise.all might be faster because the script produces the work all at once, but waiting for it to complete does not enter the interpreter (to a very rough approximation). That might be a good workaround if Promises are not as fast as they are in V8.

Comment: I don't think I can use Promise.all. I need them to execute one after another but callee API within are all promise (that is they return promises). And yes, you are correct DOM manipulation has no impact. I tried on Edge browser.

Comment: Regarding performance monitor on edge, I don't think I am able to see what you are looking for. It is not as if the browser is stuck / unresponsive while executing this. The browser keeps updating the "output" element just fine but takes 724387ms to get from 0 to 99999

Comment: Oh that's interesting! In Chrome and Firefox the update is not seen until the script finishes. By adding a `setTimeout` call to continue the loop it also took a very long time in Chrome and Firefox, since it is of course bound by actually rendering the document.

Comment: I have no idea why Edge is rendering the updated `textContent` when the script is clearly not yielding control to the browser.

Comment: See my updated output results. The Edge after running the counter to 99999 waits for another 398806ms before it finally comes to the end. As if it is clearing its built up stack - which there shouldn't be any -correct?

Comment: @JoshLee I disagree, older Chrome would paint if I interact with dom in a promise resolve function. The stack is empty even though the que is not but since there is no way of knowing when the next in que gets pushed on the stack (setTimeout or when a promise resolves) Chrome would paint on empty stack. New Chrome (and Firefox) will schedule the paint and if something gets pushed on stack from que within a certain amount of time it will not paint but consolidate changes made in the newer functions that came from que (see my anwer).

Comment: I might recommend: `await new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms))` where `ms` is the delay in milliseconds – I would guess `Promise.all` is faster because it's only using a single `await`

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with Chrome optimizing paints so when I add an element to dom and then change style in 2 different resolve functions it is handled as one action (one paint) depending how quickly the 2 dom interaction requests were made.

The following won't animate in Chrome:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#content");
Promise.resolve(el)
.then(
  _=>
    el.innerHTML = `
    <div style="position:absolute;top:100px;transition:top 2s;">hello world</div>
    `
)
.then(
  _ =>
    // setTimeout(x=>el.querySelector("div").style.top = "2px",100)
    el.querySelector("div").style.top = "2px"
);
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

If that one animates in Edge that means your `appendChild` and `innerText` causes thousands of paints in edge but doesn't in Chrome, the following will animate in Chrome and Firefox because `getBoundingClientRect` will flush scheduled changes to the dom, you could use this if add and/or animate elements in a promise chain:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#content");
Promise.resolve(el)
.then(
  _=>{
    el.innerHTML = `
    <div style="position:absolute;top:100px;transition:top 2s;">hello world</div>
    `;
    //this will trigger paint as well (in case you do want to animate)
    //  it will flush changes to the dom before getting bounding
    el.getBoundingClientRect();
  }
)
.then(
  _ =>
    // setTimeout(x=>el.querySelector("div").style.top = "2px",100)
    el.querySelector("div").style.top = "2px"
);
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: _"If that one animates in Edge that means ..."_ it did not. The second snippet animated as expected on Edge as well.